# How I am able to get specific data from website to excel?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, web, url

I have an excel. At A column of every cell has an english word. B columnd of every cell has a link that excel bridge function able to open "TURENG" translation website to find meaning of at A column english word. Then according to TURENG commenly use words I am writing C,D,E,F colums. But I want to take those words automaticly. when I press the link of B column, first 4 word of at TURENG website would write C,D,E,F columns automatically. How can I do this?

I am expecting that I want to get meanings of english words to my excel automatically

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service. Try to write your own code then, if you have a problem with it, post it in your question (as text) and explain what specific problem you have with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.